# Creating Object Inside Java Method

Tags: java, oop, object, instance-variables

```
public static String[] Form() {
        Scanner Input=new Scanner(System.in); 
        String array[];
        array = new String[2];
        RegistrationForm RegisteredStudents = new RegistrationForm();
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
            System.out.println("Enter Name");
            String name= Input.next();
            System.out.println("Enter Address");
            String address= Input.next();
            System.out.println("Enter E-Mail");
            String email= Input.next();
            System.out.println(i+1+" Student Registration complete");
            System.out.println("Your Rollnumber is "+(i+1));
            int roll=i+1;
            String array[i]=new array(name,address,email,roll);
    }
return array;}
```

is it possible to create an object inside a java method instead of creating it in main method? & can a single object be used to store different data in an array?

Comment: 1. Yes, you can create objects from any method including main. 2. Yes, as long as "different data" is of the same data type as that of the array you declared.

Comment: `new array(name,address,email,roll)` - this won't compile. You would have to create a class named `array` which would have to extend `String` - that is not possible because `String` is `final`.

Comment: Btw. please follow Java naming conventions - variable names are written in "lowerCamelCase"

Comment: You are using an array to store different properties of some entity, perhaps a student. You should create a class `Student` with those properties. You should also study the basics of object-oriented programming.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would do the trick.

I recommend you to use Arraylist instead of array, but I presume it's some class work so I don't modify too much your example.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Customer {

    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String email;
    private int roll;

    public Customer(String name, String address, String email, int roll) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.email = email;
        this.roll = roll;
    }

    public int getRoll() {
        return roll;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
}

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Customer customers[] = new Customer[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter Name");
            String name = Input.next();
            System.out.println("Enter Address");
            String address = Input.next();
            System.out.println("Enter E-Mail");
            String email = Input.next();
            System.out.println(i + 1 + " Student Registration complete");
            System.out.println("Your Rollnumber is " + (i + 1));
            int roll = i + 1;
            customers[i] = new Customer(name, address, email, roll);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create objects in any type of method in Java.So according to your code snippet ,you are trying to store a student with set of attributes in an array.To achieve this I think the best way is using an ArrayList if you are not sure about the students count that you are going to register,but if you exactly know the count[This means if you can specify the array size] you can go with an array.But in the both ways first you need to have a model class including the student attributes.After creating the Student model class you can create an array or an ArrayList type of Student.Then you can store your student details in the selected method.

Ex:

**Step 1:Creating the Student model class**

```
 public class Student {
         
        //Member variables
        private String name;
        private String address;
        private String email;
        private int roll;
    
        //Default constructor
        public Student(){}

       //Overloaded constructor
        public Student(String name, String address, String email, int roll) {
            this.name = name;
            this.address = address;
            this.email = email;
            this.roll = roll;
        }

        //Getters and Setters
        public void setRoll(int roll){
             this.roll = roll;
        }

        public int getRoll() {
            return roll;
        }
    
        public void setName(String name){
            this.name =name;   
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setAddress(String address){
            this.address = address;
        }
       
        public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }
         public void setEmail(String email){
            this.email = email;
         }
        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

    //Better if you can also implement the toString() method in here
    }
```

**Step 2:ArrayList or array implementation**

**Implementing by using an Array**

```
public class Form{

     public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
            //Creation of Student type array
            Student studentsArr[] = new Studnet[10]; //Considering there are only 10 Students to register
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                System.out.println("Enter Name");
                String name = Input.next();
                System.out.println("Enter Address");
                String address = Input.next();
                System.out.println("Enter E-Mail");
                String email = Input.next();
                int roll = i + 1;
                studentsArr[i] = new Student(name, address, email, roll);
                System.out.println(i + 1 + " Student Registration complete");
                System.out.println("Your Rollnumber is " + (i + 1));
            }
        }
}
```

**Implementing by using an ArrayList**

```
public class Form{

     public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
            //Creation of Student type array
            List<Student> studentsList = new ArrayList<>(); //Doesn't know the students count ,because of that we are using a list
            int end = 0;//Terminating condition initial value
            int key = -1;
            do{
                key++;
                System.out.println("Enter Name");
                String name = Input.next();
                System.out.println("Enter Address");
                String address = Input.next();
                System.out.println("Enter E-Mail");
                String email = Input.next();
                int roll = key + 1;
                studentsList.add(new Student(name, address, email, 
roll));//Adding the new student to list
                 System.out.println(key + 1 + " Student Registration complete");
                System.out.println("Your Rollnumber is " + (key + 1));
                System.out.println("press 0 to continue or -1 to end the process");
                end = input.nextInt();

            }while(end != -1);
      }
}
```